# Execute code to switch light on with PHP

Tags: php, nginx, raspberry-pi, gpio

I would like to execute a program using PHP, a piece of code that will use an RF transmitter to switch in my lamp.

This is achieved from the command line by:

```
action 63 A on
```

It is just a C program someone wrote to control the GPIO pins on my raspberry pi. So I make an index.php

```
<?php
exec('action 63 A off');
?>
```

It does nothing while:

```
<?php
echo exec('action');
?>
```

Gives me the default text output of the program (an explanation on parameters to use). This tells me PHP works, the program is located, it can be executed. But my lamp is not switching on. Moreover, typing on the command line:

```
php index.php
```

Does switch my lamp on/off as expected! (Using the first variety of the file)
Is Nginx (user http) not allowed to switch the lamp on/off? It is allowed to execute the file, at least, it can make it generate text output.

I also tried:

```
<?php
system('action 63 A off');
?>
```

And some more varieties like shell_exec

And thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.
The answer was easy, indeed the user "http" was not allowed to execute things from the wiringpi library which the C-program needed to run.

In the end I simply did:

```
chmod +s action
```

(This sets modifies the executable (called "action") to always run with root privileges.)
...and the code ran as expected with the following PHP file (index.php):

```
<?php
system('action 63 A off');
?>
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

is the C program a binary that you can pass parameters to? If so the following should work.

`string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )`

for example

`exec("controller.exe {$data}",$output);`

data being parameters to pass into the executable, and output being any response from the executable.

See [here](http://webtutsdepot.com/2010/03/21/c-plus-plus-php-and-jquery/) for an example

Comment: I tried `<?php echo exec('action {63 A on}',$output); ?>` it did not work. Looking into the permissions issue now...

What did work was executing `php index.php` with in there somewhere `<?php exec('action 63 A off'); ?>` as root. It must be a permissions thing.

Comment: The echo statement will send a string to output, which in the case of php is generally a browser window. it will not actually execute anything. Try setting the parameters you want to send to the "action" executable to a string variable. `$params="63 A on";` For example. Then use: `<?php exec('action {$params}',$output);` It might help to know a little more about your runtime environment as well... linux, windows, etc?

Comment: I'm running nginx on Arch Linux ARM (Raspberry Pi) but I think I found the error by `php index.php` as a regular use, it tells me: _wiringPiSetup: Must be root. (Did you forget sudo?)_ So the program I want to run does not give the http user access to WiringPi which I need to sent data to a GPIO pin (which switches my light on via an RF transmitter.) It should be doable by setting wiringpi permissions, I'll look into that later...

Answer (score 0):

Considering `echo exec('action')` is working but not `exec('action 63 A off')` , it is seeming that the command is failing if there parameters .

If that is the case , why not make two shell scripts / batch files one for `On` and one for `Off` , and call those from PHP ?

File `switch_on` contents :

```
action 63 A on
```

File `switch_off` contents :

```
action 63 A off
```

Make sure `switch_on` and `switch_off` files are accessible by PHP and have Execute permission .

switch_on.php

```
<?php
    exec('switch_on');
?>
```

switch_off.php

```
<?php
    exec('switch_off');
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this using shell scripts which I called in this way. It didn't work. Tonight I'll try both your and Chris' solution. Thanks a lot for the swift replies!

Btw, is it not strange that:

    php index.php

Does switch my lamp?
Anyway, I'll report back in about 12 hours...

Comment: [Someone already seems to have run into this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667916/php-not-executing-from-webpage-but-is-fine-from-php-cli-on-a-raspberry-pi?rq=1) I see now. Perhaps it _is_ a permissions issue and it works as root but not as user http...

As said, I'll report back in about 12 hours.